# Fetching groups and contacts from accounts other than google in my app using content providers

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Can we fetch groups and contacts from exchange, outlook, yahoo, etc.. (other than google) that are synced in our device into our app using the ContactsContract providers?

I am able to fetch the calendars and their events but unable to fetch the contacts.

The provider I am using to fetch is: [ContactContract.Groups](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Groups.html#CONTENT_SUMMARY_URI)

Comment: No. you cant get other app(s) contacts or groups. Becuase android os has limitation that you cant read other app data.

Comment: But I am able to fetch events synced into my device's calendar from these other accounts. If that is possible then surely there might be a way to fetch contacts that are synced with my device's contact app, right?